# Get multiple values of a model in Django-Rest-framework POST call

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am collecting some data making use of Django Rest Framework. I want to make an API to accept POST call and required query_set, which will be the Address. Now I want that the API should accept multiple Address, so the POST request will contain data set something like -

```
{
   {
      "some_id": id1,
      "address_line_1": some random address 1
      "address_line_2": some random address 2
   },
   {
      "some_id": id2,
      "address_line_1": some random address 1
      "address_line_2": some random address 2
   }
}
```

My address model is as following:

```
class Address(models.Model):
   some_id = models.IntegerField()
   address_line_1 = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
   address_line_2 = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
```

I have my serializer as-

```
class AddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
       model = Address
       fields = ('some_id', 'address_line_1', 'address_line_2',)
```

I am not sure which view to use to achieve this functionality. Also I want to render a form, similar to what **GenericAPIView** provides, containing all the fields of address model when I hit the API from browser. Something like-

[image: Api for a random model with fields: "first", "second"]

I am a newbie to Django Rest Framework so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your existing view type?

Comment: @一切都是空虚  I have used **APIView**. But I want to achieve the functionality of GenericAPIView. Is it possible to achieve by making changes in serializer class?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, following is not a valid JSON.

```
{
   {
      "some_id": id1,
      "address_line_1": some random address 1
      "address_line_2": some random address 2
   },
   {
      "some_id": id2,
      "address_line_1": some random address 1
      "address_line_2": some random address 2
   }
}
```

It has to have a key associated with it. So it should be something like

```
{
   addresses: [
      {
         "some_id": id1,
         "address_line_1": some random address 1
         "address_line_2": some random address 2
      },
      {
         "some_id": id2,
         "address_line_1": some random address 1
         "address_line_2": some random address 2
      }
   ]
}
```

For accepting something like above you will have to create another serializer like

```
class AddressListSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    addresses = AddressSerializer(many=True)
```

And then use above serializer in your view.